# Loop through arrays logging all combinations

Tags: javascript

I have a set of arrays for example

```
["a1", "a2"]
["b1", "b2", "b3"]
["c1", "c2"]
["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]
```

There can be any amount of these arrays.
Using the first array, is there a good way to loop through the other arrays logging each combination.

For example

```
a1,b1,c1,d1
a2,b1,c1,d1    
a1,b2,c1,d1
a2,b2,c1,d1
.
.
.
a1,b1,c1,d4
a2,b1,c1,d4
.
.
.
a1,b3,c2,d4
a2,b3,c2,d4
```

I am trying to plot the outcomes of a probability tree and this part has me stuck

Comment: @rlemon once you add the *"any amount of these arrays"* requirement, it's much less trivial.

Comment: no one said anything of trivial. I just see no effort to solve from the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an unspecified number of arrays, you can do this :

```
var arrays = [
  ["a1", "a2"],
  ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
  ["c1", "c2"],
  ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]
];
(function dive(stack) {
  if (stack.length==arrays.length) {
    console.log(stack);
  } else {
    arrays[stack.length].forEach(function(v){
        dive(stack.concat(v));
    });
  }
})([]);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/iyotet/3/edit) (open the console)

Use [a shim for forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) for old browsers if you want to support them.

Comment: See the update, the OP has completely changed the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for info. How do you find the new version ?

Comment: @ dystroy: Yowsa. Dunno, there are a *lot* of temporary objects and copies going on there. But it's cute. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Given that I understood you're question correctly, you're after the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all your sub-arrays.

Let's start by building the dumbest version possible; no cleverness, just a double-loop:

```
function product ( left, right ) {
    var ret = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < right.length; j++) {
            ret.push( [left[i], right[j]] );
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

We simply follow the definition of a product: Every item in `left` against every item in `right`. Let's clever it up a bit: We're iterating over both arrays, mapping each left item against the right one. Maybe if we use `Array#map`...

```
function product ( left, right ) {
    return left.map(function ( i ) {
        return right.map(function ( j ) {
            return [i, j];
        });
    });
}
```

However, this creates a nested array:

```
> product( [0, 1], [2, 3] );
[ [[0,2], [0,3]],
  [[1,2], [1,3]] ]
```

We can solve that by *reducing* the first array:

```
function product ( left, right ) {
    return left.reduce(function ( ret, i ) {
        var ans = right.map(function ( j ) {
            return [i, j];
        });

        return ret.concat( ans );
    }, []);
}
```

So far, this described the product `left × right`, however you wanted an n-ary product: `A × B × C × ...` How will we do that?

We will use a very useful trait of the Cartesian product: `A × B × C = A × (B × C)` . That means we can define an n-ary product recursively. Here's the first try:

```
function product ( left, right, other ) {
    if ( other ) {
        right = product.apply( this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );
    }

    return left.reduce(function ( ret, i ) {
        var ans = right.map(function ( j ) {
            return [i, j];
        });

        return ret.concat( ans );
    }, []);
}
```

The error should be clear: `[i, j]` . This assumes we have two scalars (regular, flat values), when we actually have a scalar and an array. The fix is easy: Instead of wrapping the result in an array, we concat the array to the scalar, leading to this final solution:

```
function product ( left, right, other ) {
    if ( other ) {
        right = product.apply( this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );
    }

    return left.reduce(function ( ret, i ) {
        var ans = right.map(function ( j ) {
            return [i].concat( j );
        });

        return ret.concat( ans );
    }, []);
}
```

In your case, since you have an array of arrays, when calling, you need to flatten it:

```
> var arr = [ ["a1", "a2"], ["b1", "b2", "b3"], ["c1", "c2"], ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"] ];
undefined
> product.apply( null, arr );
[ [ 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b1', 'c2', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b1', 'c2', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b1', 'c2', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b1', 'c2', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b2', 'c2', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b2', 'c2', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b2', 'c2', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b3', 'c1', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b3', 'c1', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b3', 'c1', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b3', 'c1', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b3', 'c2', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b3', 'c2', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b3', 'c2', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a1', 'b3', 'c2', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b1', 'c1', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b1', 'c1', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b1', 'c2', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b1', 'c2', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b1', 'c2', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b1', 'c2', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b2', 'c1', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b2', 'c1', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b2', 'c1', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b2', 'c1', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b3', 'c1', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b3', 'c1', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b3', 'c1', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b3', 'c1', 'd4' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b3', 'c2', 'd1' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b3', 'c2', 'd2' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b3', 'c2', 'd3' ],
  [ 'a2', 'b3', 'c2', 'd4' ] ]
```